# How to adjust the line break tag?

Tags: html, css

While trying to create a homepage for a certain company, I came across the following issue.

```
<p class="headline">Headline<br><span class="bottomline">Bottomline</span></p>
```

The following valid `HTML` code will work just fine, however I want to adjust the created space in between the content. I tried using the `margin` rule in `CSS` with no avail. The `bottomline` just won't move. Back to the question at hand: how do you insert a line break in a paragraph that you can adjust at your own will? It would appear as if my problem is a bug in my implementation. Therefore, I will provide a code snippet copied from the actual source code.

```css
div#article > div.parallex {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
}

div#article > div.parallex > p.headline {
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

span.bottomline {
  color: #c3c3c3;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="article">
    <div class="parallex">
        <p class="headline">Company<sup style="color: #37924e;">■</sup><span class="bottomline">Description</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`br`s are not the best practice for vertical spacing. Of course you can do multiple `br`s to increase the space,  but a better solution would be to use css margin or padding.

```
.bottomline {
     margin-top: 10px
 }
```

The fact that you try tu put a inline element in another inline element make your example also not work. You should use two paragraphs below each other and space them with margin.

Comment: Weirdly enough, the `margin` rule doesn't do anything. I think I have to do some troubleshooting first. But thanks for quick response anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pre` tag which preserves line-breaks and spaces or `white-space: pre` in CSS. Use `line-height` to adjust the space between the content.

```html
<pre>
Header


Text
</pre>
```

```html
<div style="white-space: pre; line-height: 10px;">
Header


Text
</div>
```

```html
<div style="white-space: pre; line-height: 50px;">
    Header


    Text
    </div>
```

```css
div#article > div.parallex {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
  white-space: pre;
}

div#article > div.parallex > p.headline {
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

span.bottomline {
  color: #c3c3c3;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="article">
    <div class="parallex">
        <p class="headline">Company<sup style="color: #37924e;">■</sup>
<span class="bottomline">Description</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While that does work, I don't think that you can adjust the space in between the content as I had requested. I can achieve the same result by using the  `<br>` tag.

Comment: @NiklasSimandi Just use `line-height` to adjust the space in between the content.

Comment: I already tried that. The line height has no effect on the text itself. I think that something is just wrong with my code.